# How to print an Eigen tensor into a text file?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I am trying to print out a 3D matrix into a text file that can be read by a MATLAB code. The example I have here prints the tensor in a text file but when I try to open it in MATLAB it reads something like 256 x 16 instead of 16x16x16.

Example:

```
static const int nx = 16;  
static const int ny = 16; 
static const int nz = 16;double Lx = 128; 
double Ly = 128;
double LZ = 128;
double dx = Lx / nx;
double dy = Ly / ny;
double dz = Lz / nz;

double a = (2 * EIGEN_PI)/Lx;
double b = (2 * EIGEN_PI)/ Ly;
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> X(nx,ny,nz); 
eXX.setZero(); 
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Y(nx,ny,nz); 
eYY.setZero(); 
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Z(nx,ny,nz); 
eZZ.setZero(); 
 
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
            X(k,i,j) = i*dx;
            Y(j,i,k) = j*dy;
            Z(j,i,k) = k*dz; 
        }

    }       
}

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Out(nx,ny,nz); 
Out.setZero(); 
    
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
                Out(k,i,j) = sin(3. * a * Z(k,i,j)) * sin(a * X(k,i,j)) * cos(b * Y(k,i,j));
               
        }

    }       
}
  std::ofstream file("test.txt");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    file << Out << '\n'; 
  }
```

I know I will probably have to write my own output routine instead os using the operator `<<` since it treats a rank-3 tensor as a 2-d matrix for the purpose of output.

Comment: You appear to be writing `100 * i + 10 * j + k`, so a vector of `[[ 100, 10, 0 ]]` seems to make sense. Why do you think writing `Test` would produce something else? It would help if you showed a [Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I added a full example code. This reproduces a 16x256 instead of 16x16x16 which is the case when I print my output in the command window.

Comment: Thank you. So `Out` is type `Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Out(nx,ny,nz); ` That will allow others to help here. I haven't used the Eigen library specifically, but will run take a look. As far as reading into Matlab goes, I'll have to look at the read format. If I recall, it will need `[` to begin and then `[ x, y, z]` for each vector in the tensor and then a closing `]`. It has been ages since I messed with it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks! I am using the built-in function MATLAB ``readmatrix
`` which might not be the right way to do it here.